# PHP result set and HTML positioning

Tags: php, html

I have problem with positioning html tags I did try to solve the problem but for me the code looks fine however the output tells something different I did try do to sort out the output of SQL query however I wasn't able to achieve this and when I did asked for help in the forum in reply I get that it would be much easier to do it in PHP. So I have produce following code but I am not getting required results:

```
 <body>

<div class="container">
    <?php  
        $sdate = '';
            foreach($rows as $row) {
                if($row['shieldDate'] != $sdate){
                    $sdate = $row['shieldDate'];
                    echo '<h2>';
                    echo $row['shieldDate'],'&nbsp','opponent','&nbsp',$row['shieldTeam'];
                    echo '</h2>';

                     echo "
                     <p>The .table class adds basic styling (light padding and only horizontal dividers) to a table:</p>            
                      <table class='table'>
                        <thead>
                          <tr>
                            <th>Player</th>
                            <th>Score</th>
                          </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                                ";

            echo "<tr>";        
            echo "<td>";
            echo $row["firstname"],'&nbsp', $row["lastname"];
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo $row["score"];
            echo "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";

            }else{

            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo $row["firstname"],'&nbsp', $row["lastname"];
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo $row["score"];
            echo "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";

            }
        }               
    ?>

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

</body>
```

I am trying to acheive following output:
[image]

However I am getting:

[image]

Comment: Rather than a screenshot it would be better to have the HTML source output. You don't close your `tbody` and `table` tags.

Comment: you never change tables when a date changes, so you just keep nesting tables deeper and deeper.

Comment: those tags are closed straight after the end of php

Comment: Please show the complete code then, and the HTML. You should close you `table` after the end of a "date group", not only at the end of the whole loop.

Comment: can you tell me where is the problem because I cannot see it, which part of code I have to change to make it right

Comment: I just change the code to display everything in body tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't close your `tbody` and `table` tags between two dates.
Each time you encounter a new date, you open a new `table` tag, but you never close it before having a new `h2` date title. Add a line to close it.

```
$sdate = '';
foreach($rows as $row) {
    if($row['shieldDate'] != $sdate){
    // It's a new date
        if (!empty($sdate)) {
        // It's not the first date: close previous table
            echo '</tbody></table>';
        }

        $sdate = $row['shieldDate'];
        echo '<h2>';
        echo $row['shieldDate'],'&nbsp','opponent','&nbsp',$row['shieldTeam'];
        echo '</h2>';

        echo "<p>The .table class adds basic styling (light padding and only horizontal dividers) to a table:</p>            
            <table class='table'>
                <thead>[...]</thead>
                <tbody>";

                [...]
    } else {

        [...]

    }
}  

if (!empty($sdate)) {
    // There has been at least one date (at least one table): close it
    echo '</tbody></table>';
}
```

Note that the `[...]` content is the same in `if` and `else` instructions.

You could do this to have something cleaner. The less duplicate code you have, the more easy it is to read. The more easy to read your code is, the better.

```
foreach($rows as $row) {
    if($row['shieldDate'] != $sdate){
        // Do your h2 and open table stuff
    }

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>";
    // etc. No need to put it in the if AND in the else instructions.
}
```

Comment: Note that the `[...]` content is the same in `if` and `else` instructions. You could remove if from the `if`, don't have any `else`, and just echo it each time after the `if`. (Not sure I'm clear, I'll edit my answer.)